# a trouble with the training unit 3.6 from ROS-I

Tags: ros, path-planning, c++, moveit, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm doing the tutorials from ROS-Industrial, and i have a problem with this:

http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/3.6

In the steps 5 and 6 from the first part i Have this problem

```
jaam002@jaam002:~/industrial_training/training/work/3.6$ rosrun lesson_move_group lesson_move_group 
[ INFO] [1444515389.737938520]: Loading robot model 'abb_irb2400'...
[ INFO] [1444515389.893979856]: Loading robot model 'abb_irb2400'...
[ INFO] [1444515390.713263586]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group manipulator.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'class_loader::LibraryUnloadException'
  what():  Attempt to unload library that class_loader is unaware of.
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

the robot plan succesfully the path, but it doesn't execute the path.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218945/a-trouble-with-the-training-unit-3.6-from-ros-i/) by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The errors you listed (`LibraryUnloadException`) are a known issue when disposing of a `MoveGroup` object (see [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/592)), but should not affect the observed planning or execution.

Check the terminal window in which you launched the `move_group` node (not the same window as above) for additional error messages.  Are you sure that the planning was completed successfully?  The ROS-I tutorial you reference tries to move the robot to a random joint position, which is not always reachable by the robot.  You may see failure messages related to "unreachable position" or similar.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2015-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-10-13**:
thanks so much Jeremy, i could finally execute the path, it was just a mistake with the rviz